# OpenVPN administration GUI

Tags: vpn, openvpn, graphical-user-interface

Is there a GUI for OpenVPN ? anything I can use to administrate it easily and perhaps create groups of users etc? with access restrictions on specific groups etc?

I can't afford to pay for licenses for their commercial product

Alternatively is there something else you would recommend ?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: If somebody is paying you then your time isn't free. Keep that in mind when you say you can't afford to spend any money.

Comment: Cost of employee who already works for the company is often taken as granted by management. Spending things on software is additional cost which is often treated as not needed. Often Boards don't understand this and it's likely the case here.

Comment: Linux flavored operating system, Madboy your comment is correct

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for an "easy to use" option, i strongly suggest finding some money (its really cheap...)  and getting OpenVPN-AS.   Its a paid for service, but it is absolutely phenomenal when it comes to an easy to install, easy to use vpn system

It comes with 2 (or three, i can't remember) users for free to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a GUI for the server, but if you have a spare server or VM available you may consider installing an integrated firewall/VPN gateway appliance. Some of them use OpenVPN and make at least the initial setup and the process of adding users easy:

Linux:

http://www.ipcop.org/

http://www.endian.com/us/

FreeBSD:

http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/VPN_Capability_OpenVPN